# How can I run two commands in succession from cron?

Tags: cron, scheduling

I have 2 commands that need to run every hour, so I put these in /etc/cron.hourly/hrcron file, in following format

```
command1; command2
```

It should've worked in my opinion, but does anyone have any idea what's stopping it from running?

I'm running CentOS 6.8.

Comment: Just [separate the commands with double ampersands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9640258): `command1 && command2`

Comment: @l0b0 I know syntax with && but semicolon should work too, as it works in terminal. Is it not so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Files placed in `/etc/cron.hourly`, `cron.daily` and `cron.monthly` need to be executables. If you place a text file with a single line as shown in your question into that directory, it cannot be run at all for the same reason that you could not run such a file as a shell script from the command line, either.

What you mean to say is this:

```shell
#!/bin/sh
command1
command2
```

You could concatenate the second and third lines with a semicolon, but it simply isn't necessary here. It's a full-on shell script, so you don't need to "stack" commands in that way.

Also, be sure to mark the script executable, else it still won't run.

If all of this seems odd to you, based on your knowledge of [`crontab` entries](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab), realize that executables in these directories are typically run by either [`anacron`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron) or [`run-parts`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-run-parts/), not by `cron`. Thus, the information from `man 5 crontab` doesn't really apply here.

Comment: Another thing one may stumble on is cron not finding the commands.  Mine were installed in `/usr/local/bin`, which is not in the default $PATH. So: 1) make sure the commands are executable, 2) specify the path

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way to do so is to create two files

- `/etc/cron.hourly/file1` containing `command1`
- `/etc/cron.hourly/file2` containing `command2`

I do not recommend having a single cronjob running `command1 && command2` because if the first command fails, the second will never execute by design.

Edit: in case you need command1 to be run before command2, use the standard `/etc/crontab` file and fill it in as such:

```
0 * * * *  root  command1
5 * * * *  root  command2
```

This will run command1 at 00 mins each hour and command2 at 05 mins each hour.

Comment: Would that guarantee sequential execution of `command1` before `command2`?

Comment: No.  In case you need this you can simply use the standard crontab file,  adding entries `0 * * * * command1` and `5 * * * * command2`.  This will run command1 at 00 mins each hour and command2 at 05 mins each hour.

Comment: *"if the first command fails, the second will never execute by design."* Well, maybe that's why OP specified separation by `;` not `&&`?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The use of `&&` was advised by @l0b0.